# Open PDF in web page of ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

I want to open PDF in ASP.NET aspx page. I dont want to export a pdf file.

Need just write pdf file in ASPX page same as we are writing bytes into Image control.

Comment: you have to use third party dlls for this purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got the answer , it is too simple.

I have answered here.

```
Response.Clear();
string filePath = "myfile.pdf";
Response.contentType = "application/pdf";
Response.WriteFile(filePath);
Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the pdf document in an IFrame in your page.

Comment: Yes, I can but I got the answer too. I have posted here please check.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:
Here FullPath is full path of file with file name

```
Dim f1 As New FileStream(FullPath, FileMode.Open)
Dim m1(f1.Length) As Byte
f1.Read(m1, 0, f1.Length)
f1.Close()
File.Delete(FullPath)
Response.ClearHeaders()
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
Response.Clear()
Response.OutputStream.Write(m1, 0, m1.GetLength(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

to Create PDF-Files you can use a library like pdfsharp
http://pdfsharp.com/

you can easily create PDFs with that. Example Code:

```
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
PdfPage page = document.AddPage();
...
```

and then save it on your Server

```
document.Save(filename);
```

then just link to it via an a-href or in an iframe.