# iFrame launching new window for PDF

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, iframe, adobe-reader

Okay so I am having some trouble finding an answer for this through google.

I am trying to setup a site using c# that will display an embedded PDF on the page using dynamic file names.  Here is my code:

```
aspx: < iframe style="vertical-align:auto" name="pdfIframe" id="pdfIframe" width="1024px" height="1200px" runat =server></iframe >

cs: pdfIframe.Attributes["src"] = @"" + fullfilepath;
```

"fullfilepath" is a string that contains the file path for the pdf I want to open.  The problem I'm running into is that the PDF is opening fine when I run the debugger but once I publish the site and navigate to it from another PC it opens the pdf in Adobe Reader and not the iframe regardless of what browser I am using.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: (The string literal isn't really needed as there are no characters that need to be escaped - that includes the data within fullfilepath.) Did you use the solution from this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11646665/open-pdf-in-web-page-of-asp-net

Comment: No I didn't get my answer there.  I took the literal out and it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: I should add that when I launch the same app in Chrome it doesn't open the PDF in the iframe or Adobe, it just doesn't launch.

Comment: What is the string value of fullfilepath?

Comment: I put that code into my project and it tried to save the pdf to my local machine.

Comment: Sorry, but again, what is the value of fullfilepath?

Comment: Full filepath is the value of some text and two other strings put together, looks something like this:
`serverinfo = @"\\servername\e$\folder\folder";`
`pdfname = "MAC" + account + "." + procid + ".pdf";`
`fullfilepath = serverinfo + pdfname;`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43541/discussion-between-christopher-walker-and-matt-p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my problem was that the file path I was using @"\servername\e$\folder\folder" needed to be shared out and changed to "\servername\folder\folder".  It's funny how two characters can screw up your whole project and steal two hours of your day!